# Stored Procedure with local and input variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures, variable-declaration

I am trying to create a procedure that I can specify 2 input variables and have a number of local procedure variables that will return a SQL query results table.

This is the code that I have written to do it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MS_Field_Mapping( 
    @MS_Table_Name VARCHAR(100), 
    @DCW_No VARCHAR(10)
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;


DECLARE @Rsrc_Mapping varchar(100);
DECLARE @Appt_Types_Rsrc varchar(100);
DECLARE @Appt_Type_Settings varchar(100);

SET @Rsrc_Mapping = 'REF_'+@DCW_No+'_Rsrc_Mapping'
SET @Appt_Types_Rsrc = 'REF_'+@DCW_No+'_Appt_Types_Rsrc'
SET @Appt_Type_Settings = 'REF_'+@DCW_No+'_Appt_Type_Settings'

PRINT @Rsrc_Mapping
PRINT @Appt_Types_Rsrc
PRINT @Appt_Type_Settings

SELECT mst.Main_Bookshelf_Old
    ,mst.Main_Bookshelf_New
    ,mst.Main_Bookshelf_New_Mirror
    ,mst.Scndry_Bookshelf_Old
    ,mst.Scndry_Bookshelf_New
    ,mst.Scndry_Bookshelf_New_Mirror
    ,mst.Book_Name_Old
    ,mst.Book_Name_New
    ,mst.Book_Name_New_Mirror
    ,mst.Scndry_Book_Name_Old
    ,mst.Scndry_Book_Name_New
    ,mst.Scndry_Book_Name_New_Mirror
    ,mst.Tertiary_Book_Old
    ,mst.Tertiary_Book_New
    ,mst.Amb_Loc_Old
    ,mst.Amb_Loc_New
    ,mst.Rsrc_Old
    ,mst.Rsrc_New
    ,mst.Rsrc_New_Mirror
    ,eus.Clinic_Type
    ,mst.Protocol_Old
    ,mst.Protocol_New
    ,mst.Appt_Type_Old
    ,mst.Appt_Type_New
    ,cmn.Accept_Format_Name
    ,atr.Slot_Name
    ,NULL AS Orders
    ,rm.Service_Provider_Type
    ,mst.Multi_Rsrc_Clin
    ,mst.Known_Addit_Providers
    ,mst.Wait_list_Old
    ,ats.RL_Queue AS Wait_List_New
    ,cmn.MO_Tier2_Code
    ,cmn.MO_Tier2_Name
    ,cmn.OHP_Tier2_Code
    ,cmn.OHP_Tier2_Name
    ,cmn.CCC
    ,cmn.CCC_Name
    ,cmn.Delivery_Method
    ,cmn.Patient_Visit_Type
    ,cmn.Session_Type
    ,cmn.Care_Type
    ,eus.Delivery_Setting
    ,cmn.Appt_Class
    ,cmn.OOS_Inc
FROM @MS_Table_Name mst
INNER JOIN dbo.REF_DCW_CMN_Appt_Setting_Map cmn
    ON mst.Appt_Type_New = cmn.Appt_Type_Name
LEFT JOIN @Rsrc_Mapping rm
    ON mst.Rsrc_New = rm.Rsrc_Mnemonic
INNER JOIN @Appt_Types_Rsrc atr
    ON mst.Appt_Type_New = atr.Appt_Type_Name
        AND mst.Amb_Loc_New = atr.Amb_Loc
        AND mst.Rsrc_New = atr.Rsrc_Available
INNER JOIN dbo.REF_EUS_Appt_Info eus
    ON mst.Appt_Type_Old = eus.Appt_Type
LEFT JOIN @Appt_Type_Settings ats
    ON mst.Appt_Type_New = ats.Appt_Type_Name
        AND mst.Amb_Loc_New = ats.Amb_Loc
RETURN
GO
```

But I'm getting these errors. I am declaring the variables so I don't understand why it say that i need to declare them and two are input variables.

> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MS_Field_Mapping, Line 73
>   Must declare the table variable "@MS_Table_Name".
>
> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MS_Field_Mapping, Line 76
>   Must declare the table variable "@Rsrc_Mapping".
>
> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MS_Field_Mapping, Line 78
>   Must declare the table variable "@Appt_Types_Rsrc".
>
> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MS_Field_Mapping, Line 84
>   Must declare the table variable "@Appt_Type_Settings".

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use a variable for table names and column names. You should use dynamic SQL instead. Be aware of the consequences though. For more about this, read: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: I'm not I am only using it for table names cause they conform to a naming standard and I don't want to have to type 5 table names every time i want to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL to execute with the table name in variable. Use the below code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MS_Field_Mapping( 
@MS_Table_Name VARCHAR(100), 
@DCW_No VARCHAR(10)
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;


DECLARE @Rsrc_Mapping varchar(100);
DECLARE @Appt_Types_Rsrc varchar(100);
DECLARE @Appt_Type_Settings varchar(100);

SET @Rsrc_Mapping = 'REF_'+@DCW_No+'_Rsrc_Mapping'
SET @Appt_Types_Rsrc = 'REF_'+@DCW_No+'_Appt_Types_Rsrc'
SET @Appt_Type_Settings = 'REF_'+@DCW_No+'_Appt_Type_Settings'

PRINT @Rsrc_Mapping
PRINT @Appt_Types_Rsrc
PRINT @Appt_Type_Settings

DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @QRY ='

SELECT mst.Main_Bookshelf_Old
    ,mst.Main_Bookshelf_New
    ,mst.Main_Bookshelf_New_Mirror
    ,mst.Scndry_Bookshelf_Old
    ,mst.Scndry_Bookshelf_New
    ,mst.Scndry_Bookshelf_New_Mirror
    ,mst.Book_Name_Old
    ,mst.Book_Name_New
    ,mst.Book_Name_New_Mirror
    ,mst.Scndry_Book_Name_Old
    ,mst.Scndry_Book_Name_New
    ,mst.Scndry_Book_Name_New_Mirror
    ,mst.Tertiary_Book_Old
    ,mst.Tertiary_Book_New
    ,mst.Amb_Loc_Old
    ,mst.Amb_Loc_New
    ,mst.Rsrc_Old
    ,mst.Rsrc_New
    ,mst.Rsrc_New_Mirror
    ,eus.Clinic_Type
    ,mst.Protocol_Old
    ,mst.Protocol_New
    ,mst.Appt_Type_Old
    ,mst.Appt_Type_New
    ,cmn.Accept_Format_Name
    ,atr.Slot_Name
    ,NULL AS Orders
    ,rm.Service_Provider_Type
    ,mst.Multi_Rsrc_Clin
    ,mst.Known_Addit_Providers
    ,mst.Wait_list_Old
    ,ats.RL_Queue AS Wait_List_New
    ,cmn.MO_Tier2_Code
    ,cmn.MO_Tier2_Name
    ,cmn.OHP_Tier2_Code
    ,cmn.OHP_Tier2_Name
    ,cmn.CCC
    ,cmn.CCC_Name
    ,cmn.Delivery_Method
    ,cmn.Patient_Visit_Type
    ,cmn.Session_Type
    ,cmn.Care_Type
    ,eus.Delivery_Setting
    ,cmn.Appt_Class
    ,cmn.OOS_Inc
FROM '+@MS_Table_Name+' mst
INNER JOIN dbo.REF_DCW_CMN_Appt_Setting_Map cmn
    ON mst.Appt_Type_New = cmn.Appt_Type_Name
LEFT JOIN '+@Rsrc_Mapping+' rm
    ON mst.Rsrc_New = rm.Rsrc_Mnemonic
INNER JOIN '+@Appt_Types_Rsrc+' atr
    ON mst.Appt_Type_New = atr.Appt_Type_Name
        AND mst.Amb_Loc_New = atr.Amb_Loc
        AND mst.Rsrc_New = atr.Rsrc_Available
INNER JOIN dbo.REF_EUS_Appt_Info eus
    ON mst.Appt_Type_Old = eus.Appt_Type
LEFT JOIN '+@Appt_Type_Settings+' ats
    ON mst.Appt_Type_New = ats.Appt_Type_Name
        AND mst.Amb_Loc_New = ats.Amb_Loc
        '
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QRY     

RETURN
GO
```

Comment: K. If correct, please mark as answer @Lucas Perrett

Comment: @LucasPerrett - If this answer solved your then mark it as answer by selecting the tick mark to the left of this answer